Sonatype Nexus menu option "Data Store" is not shown
Sonatype Nexus makes some changes about used database starting from 3.71.0 version.
We actually use 3.70.1.
In order to determine which Database we are using I have to see "Administration → Repository → Data Store" as explained here :
https://help.sonatype.com/en/data-store.html
But the problem that in my Admin interface I don't see "Data Store" menu. Just after "Blob Stores" we have "Proprietary Repositories".
Does anyone know why I don't see "Data Store" and how to fix it ?

If you do not see "data store" that means your instance is using the OrientDb database.   The "data store" UI only shows up for h2 or PostgreSQL.

Thank you @rseddon. Sorry for late reply (I found the answer by myself, so I didn't check the answers on this post). Would you like to copy your comment as a normal reply ? This way I could validate it. I think it will be usefull for others peoples who could encounter similar problem.

We are on 3.72.0-04 but Data Store is not shown

Okay, i see: The Data Store screen only appears for those with a valid Nexus Repository Pro license who are using either an H2 or PostgreSQL database; it will not appear for OSS deployments or any deployment using OrientDB.

@GenaBatalski : yes, as indicated by rseddon if you don't see "Data Store" it means that you use OrientDB.

@PaulZakharov no, i'm on the h2 db (3.72.0 dropped orientdb support), but for the OSS version the Data Store view doesn't appear

If you do not see "data store" that means your instance is using the OrientDb database. The "data store" UI only shows up for h2 or PostgreSQL.
